# Testing forms and widgets - Python

Tags: django, django-forms

I trying to test the Django forms and widgets but it is returning false instead of true. The test looks right but not sure.I have added the test form, interest form and player class

```
class TestForm(TestCase):
    def test_player_interests_fail(self):
        form = PlayerInterestsForm(data={'interests': 'sport'})
        self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(), True)


class PlayerInterestsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('interests', )
        widgets = {'interests': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}


class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    tournaments = models.ManyToManyField(Tournament, through='TakenTournament')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_player')

    def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz):
        answered_questions = self.quiz_answers\
            .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz)\
            .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
        questions = quiz.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
        return questions

    def get_unanswered_tournament_questions(self, tournament):
        answered_questions = self.tournament_answers\
            .filter(answer__question__tournament=tournament)\
            .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
        questions = tournament.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
        return questions

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Player"
```

Comment: Please show us the `Player` model, in particular the `interests` field.

Comment: There you go @solarissmoke

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `Player.interests` is a `ManyToManyField`. That means the form expects the data to be a list of primary keys for the selected `Subject`s - passing a string value will not work. You have to pass integer IDs of `Subject` objects.
2. A `CheckboxSelectMultiple` allows multiple objects to be selected, which means you have to pass a list, not a single value.

So you need to do something like this:

```
def test_player_interests_fail(self):
    # If you haven't already, you need to create a Subject
    # I don't know how your Subject model is defined, but something like this
    s = Subject.objects.create(name='Sport')

    form = PlayerInterestsForm(data={'interests': [s.pk]})
    self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(), True)
```